# Как при выходе из приложения вызвать диалоговое окно?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

Подскажите, как при выходе из приложения, когда нажимаю кнопку "выйти" (которая отвечает за метод finish), вызвать диалоговое окно. Именно когда  `showDialog(DIALOG_EXIT);` я это ставлю в метод finish(); окно вызывается, я прописал, что если `if(int a <1){ showDialog(DIALOG_EXIT);`, что мне нужно прописать, чтобы закрыть приложение. Или вообще по другому нужно сделать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно показывать диалог не в момент завершения программы, что и делает метод `onFinish` а показывать когда вы нажимаете кнопку выхода, и если юзер согласен выйти то вызывать метод `onFinish`. Как-то так должно быть:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
        .setTitle(R.string.quit)
        .setMessage(R.string.really_quit)
        .setPositiveButton(R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                finish();    
            }

        })
        .setNegativeButton(R.string.no, null)
        .show();
```

это пример диалога для выхода, вам нужно будет поставить свой показ диалога, но до того как вызывается метод `onFinish`

### UPDATE

чтобы сохранить переменную в память и не показывать диалог то нужно сохранить в переменную и потом ее проверять:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(); 
Boolean statusLocked = prefs.edit().putBoolean("locked", true).commit();
```

и дальше проверяете:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(); 
if (prefs.getBoolean("locked", locked) {
   
} else {
   
}
```

Comment: я хотел, так чтобы если уже один раз человек оставил отзыв, на пример добавилась 1, и тогда окно уже не вызывается. Как то так...

Comment: Вообщем, понял без вариантов))) Спасибо ))

Comment: @АндрейМостовенко,  обновил ответ. Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него

Comment: у меня не в том проблема, как переменные проверять и сохранять, это понятно (спасибо), тут момент, именно выхода с приложения и перед выходом показывать диалоговое окно.

Comment: чтобы показать диалог перед выходом можете использовать код представленный в моем ответе, при выходе вы завершаете активность вызывая метод onfinish  так вот перед вызовом метода показывайте диалог и если пользователь согласен выйти то уже тогда вызывайте onfinish

Comment: ок, спасибо, попробую

Comment: @АндрейМостовенко Возможно, вам надо не метод жизненного цикла использовать, но нажатие на кнопку назад? или под выходом вы имеете в виду в т.ч. сворачивание приложения?

Comment: я конкретно имею ввиду кнопку назад, которая внизу экрана по умолчанию в андроид. Я пока решил это немного по другому. Что через определенное количество открытий приложения, появится диалоговое окно. Это я для оценки приложения вообще делаю. Чтобы приложение могли оценить.

Answer (score 0):

Я капитан очевидность! Мне всего то нужно было вызвать диалог в onBackPressed();,
после чего в окне уже если мне нужно вызываю finish();